# Copy signal value in DVE

Tags: simulator, waveform, synopsys-vcs

I'm using Synopsys DVE simulator and want to copy value from the waveform window, but I cannot find any button or option to do this. Ctrl+C copies the full path of the signal, but not the current value of the signal. The DVE user guide does not mention this function, but I think this can be done. Any suggestion is well-appreciated.
For example, in the following screenshot, how to copy the value 14'h001e?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move the mouse over the signal, then press shift to save the signal in the Tooltip viewer. Finally copy to clipboard. Is that easy.

[image: Tooltip Viewer]